# Query nested array with another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections: transactions and products, where transaction has the id of the buyer and products has an array of buyers:

transaction example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6125439fda2f9d88542548af"),
  user: ObjectId("612544fe328f853180161f85"),
  product: ObjectId("61254520e07efecc99fcdf7b"),
  status: "CANCELED"
}
```

product example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("61254520e07efecc99fcdf7b"),
  name: "Product A",
  buyers: [{
    buyer: ObjectId("612544fe328f853180161f85"),
    otherProps: "example"
  }]
}
```

I need to find all transactions where status is "CANCELED" and the buyer is not in the buyers array at product collection. I try:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  { $match: { status: 'CANCELED' } },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'products',
    localField: 'product',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'product'
  } },
  { $match: { $expr: { $ne: ["$product.buyers.buyer", "$user"] } } },
])
```

But the not equal doesn't work and the query return product where the user is buyer.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can try this aggregation query, using `pipeliine` into `$lookup` to get the desired result.

- First `$match` by `CANCELED` status.
- Then `$lookup` using a `pipeline`. Into the pipeline first `$match` by desired `_id` and `$$user` not in `$buyers.buyer` array.

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": "CANCELED"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "let": {
        "id": "$_id",
        "buyers": "$buyers",
        "user": "$user"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$product",
                    "$id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$not": {
                    "$in": [
                      "$$user",
                      "$buyers.buyer"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "product"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_5z-AxH79cM)

In the example only "Product B" is retrieved into `product` array because user is `612544fe328f853180161f85` and `Product A` and `Product C` has at least one buyer with id `612544fe328f853180161f85`.

Another example with more data [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_yAoq05pUoD)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping JF! I only had to make a small change because I need to know the products that the user has canceled transaction and is not one of the buyers (to send a cart recovery email).

So I had to change the $eq inside the pipeline to bring only the transaction product and after the lookup I added a match to remove the unsuccessful lookups: [changed example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UEwSQrgVeuG).

Comment: And thank you for introducing this great tool that is Mongo Playground.